# How to set property in Textfield?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to set a property for a *textField* element in the *jrxml* file.

I have read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290621/force-jasper-html-report-to-wrap-text-by-breaking-mid-word/27471959#27471959) and I would like to set the *net.sf.jasperreports.text.save.line.breaks* property in TextField as mentioned in the comments.

I have tried:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">             
    <reportElementx="409" y="170" width="300" height="14"/>
    <textElement>
        <font fontName="Courier New" size="8"/>
    </textElement>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.save.line.breaks" value="true"/>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{field}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

But the compiler says:

> Invalid content was found starting with element 'property'

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `property` element needs to go in `reportElement`

```
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">             
            <reportElement key="textField-2" positionType="Float" x="409" y="170" width="300" height="14" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.save.line.breaks" value="true"/>
            </reportElement>
            ...
```